# The importance of differentiable dynamics from outside dynamics? (mainly topology)

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry, symplectic-topology

**I'm looking for examples that highlight how dynamical systems (particularly, Hamiltonian and Reeb dynamics) can be used to shed light in other areas of mathematics.** This could potentially include proposed connections in the form of conjectures, etc.

As an example of the sort of ideas I'm looking for: Hofer-Zehnder capacities are defined in terms of the dynamics of certain Hamiltonian functions on a symplectic manifold; in turn capacities can be used to prove several nice results including the Gromov non-squeezing theorem which is an important result in symplectic topology. Capacities are the only example I know of dynamics being exploited in (symplectic) topology. As I pointed out, I am no expert in this field so I'm sure more examples exist.

A more concrete question (focused on topology) could be the following:

**What do (Hamiltonian, Reeb) dynamics tell us about the (symplectic, contact) topology of a (symplectic, contact) manifold?**

EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments this might be a bit of a misleading question. Examples coming from different fields are most welcome, although I am more interested in applications to topology it would also be nice to hear about other areas. However, let me just narrow the category to differentiable dynamical systems.

Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the parts of your question that seemed mostly argumentative, but you may want to rewrite the question in order to make it more concrete. A list of important and, indeed, fundamental applications of dynamics to other areas of mathematics from number theory to topology would be huge.

Comment: On the question about what Hamiltonian dynamics can say about the topology of a symplectic manifold: McDuff and Salamon's book is a nice introduction, but there are now a number of books on Floer or Morse homology that you may find interesting.

Comment: The title of the question does not seem to be very well aligned with its content: I drifted in here expecting to read about applications to Ramsey theory, spectral theory, Diophantine approximation, analysis of algorithms...

Comment: Ergodic theory has applications basically everywhere - density of primes in number theory, rigidity theory for lattices in algebraic groups, all over the place in Riemannian geometry (geodesic flow on nonpositively curved manifolds), probability theory...

Comment: Also, you vastly understate the extent to which Hamiltonian dynamics is exploited in symplectic and contact geometry.  The hardest theorems in these areas (as well as 3 and 4 manifold theory) are being proved using Heegaard-Floer homology and its relatives (symplectic homology, contact homology...) The dynamics of the Hamiltonian flow is central to the construction of these theories.

Comment: I have several truly remarkable examples but they all concern holomorphic dynamics (not Hamiltonian or Reeb). If this is also allowed I will write about them.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: "I have discovered a truly marvellous example of this, which the scope of this question is too narrow to contain..."

Comment: @Ian, sorry, I agree the title might be a bit misleading, I am editing it right now. At first it was not my intention to narrow it down, should've written the title at the end!

Comment: @Paul I didn't mean to understate anything, I pointed to the example I was familiar with, I was not trying to make a list; what you write about is exactly the type of examples I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of influence in negative curvature through the geodesic flow. Here are two examples from the top of my head:

1) Farrell-Jones "asymptotic/focal transfer tool" (= geodesic flow on the unit tangent bundle of M), which is needed for one of the major steps (construction of controlled h-cobordism) their celebrated topological rigidity theorem:
If M is a non-positively curved closed manifold of dimension >4 and f:M->N is a homotopy equivalence then f is homotopic to a homeomorphism.

2) For Otal/Croke result on marked length spectrum rigidity for negatively curved surfaces the geodesic flow is instrumental. In particular, coincidence of marked length spectra immediately imply existence of a true conjugacy for the geodesic flows via Livshits theorem.

Adding a recent one: Kahn-Marcovic proof of abundance of surface subgroups in hyperbolic 3-manifolds uses dynamics of 2-frame flows.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an application with which I have first hand experience.

In the sixties J.J. Schaeffer conjectured that the girth of a normed space---the infimum of the lengths of all continuous curves on its unit sphere that join a pair of antipodal points---equals the girth of its dual space.

The normed space is not necessarily complete nor finite-dimensional. Schaeffer proved the conjecture in dimension two (a fun thing to do even in the case of $\ell_p$) and showed that it sufficed to prove the conjecture in finite dimensions.

In [this paper](http://muse.jhu.edu/login?auth=0&type=summary&url=/journals/american_journal_of_mathematics/v128/128.2paiva.pdf) the conjecture is settled using some very simple Hamiltonian dynamics. The proof is in slick modern language, but a little tinkering gives a proof that would have been immediately comprehensible to Birkhoff and Poincaré. An added bonus: the same proof gives Cauchy's integral-geometric formula and its generalization to all finite-dimensional normed spaces.